# Too many open files (CentOS7) - already tried setting higher limits

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, php-fpm

First time setting up a VPS – being mindful not to ask here unless I done due diligence and provide context.

On my remote VPS, through the terminal, almost all commands I run end up with an `Error: Too many open files` message and I need your help to move forward.

I run: `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)` on a machine with 1 CPU core and 2048Mb RAM. It has been setup with a LEMP stack `Nginx 1.16.1, PHP-FPM 7.3.9, MariaDb 10.4.8` intended for a simple wordpress site.

I have tried:

1. Google and forum searches.
2. Applied these settings (manually restarting VPS manually via control panel each time):

System-wide settings in `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
nginx       soft    nofile      1024
nginx       hard    nofile      65536
root        hard    nofile      65536
root        soft    nofile      1024
```

adjustments to memory limits and uploads in `/etc/php.ini`:

```
memory_limit = 256M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 128M
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
max_input_vars = 3000
```

PHP rlimit settings in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`:

```
rlimit_files = 65535
```

Setting NGINX limits (and other settings) in `nginx.conf`:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  10000;
}

worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    client_header_buffer_size 10k;
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 256k;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
}
```

Here is the output of `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr`:

```
45216   0   6520154
```

Here is the output of `ps aux|grep nginx|grep -v grep`:

```
root       928  0.0  0.0  46440  1192 ?        Ss   00:25   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx      929  0.0  0.2  50880  6028 ?        S    00:25   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx     9973  0.0  0.1 171576  4048 ?        S    04:28   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     9974  0.0  0.1 171576  4048 ?        S    04:28   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     9975  0.0  0.1 171576  4048 ?        S    04:28   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     9976  0.0  0.1 171576  4048 ?        S    04:28   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     9977  0.0  0.1 171576  4052 ?        S    04:28   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

Switching user to `nginx` with `su - nginx` and checking limits with:
`ulimit -Sn` returns `1024`
`ulimit -Hn`returns `65536`

The `lsof | wc -l` command returns: `4776`

Hope you can help steer me in the right direction to solve the Too Many Files problem!

**EDIT**
- the following command shows more info:

`service nginx restart`

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart nginx.service
Error: Too many open files
Job for nginx.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@pars ~]# systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
           └─worker_files_limit.conf
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Fri 2019-09-13 05:32:23 CEST; 14s ago
     Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
  Process: 1113 ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1125 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 870 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/virtualizor.service/system.slice/nginx.service

Sep 13 05:32:22 pars.work systemd[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
Sep 13 05:32:22 pars.work systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/nginx.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Sep 13 05:32:22 pars.work systemd[1]: Failed to set a watch for nginx.service's PID file /var/run/nginx.pid: Too many open files
Sep 13 05:32:23 pars.work systemd[1]: Failed to kill control group: Input/output error
Sep 13 05:32:23 pars.work systemd[1]: Failed to kill control group: Input/output error
Sep 13 05:32:23 pars.work systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.
Sep 13 05:32:23 pars.work systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Sep 13 05:32:23 pars.work systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not actually open file handles that have run out, but inotify watches.

You can see this in the error message:

```
Sep 13 05:32:22 pars.work systemd[1]: Failed to set a watch for nginx.service's PID file /var/run/nginx.pid: Too many open files
```

To solve the problem, you need to raise the number of inotify watches the system has available. If you actually check, you will find it has some ridiculously low value like 8192.

```
$ sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 8192
```

You can set the sysctl `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` to a higher value persistently by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf` or creating a file in the `/etc/sysctl.d` directory. For example, my system has:

```
$ cat /etc/sysctl.d/10-user-watches.conf 
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 1048576
```

And then load it with `sysctl -p`.

You may not want to go straight to that number and [cause the kernel to allocate memory to track a million user file watch slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535768/what-is-a-reasonable-amount-of-inotify-watches-with-linux); instead, just take the current value and double it until the problem stops occurring.

Comment: sounds great, tried adding it to /etc/sysctl.conf and loading it with sysctl -p without success, checking with your command upon reboot shows the same 8192 value. Any hints? What do I name the new file you suggest?

Comment: @HenrikSöderlund You could use the path I suggested in the answer.

Comment: I followed your instruction, created a similar file and hit the sysctl -p command after as well, but the value is still stuck at 8192 I'm afraid. I did add in the fs.file-max=100000 in the file as well on a separate line btw. Any ideas what might be preventing it from loading the setting?

Comment: extra info: It seems to state "Read-only file system" whenever I run sysctl-p or try other copy/paste commands from google with echo echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p etc.

Comment: What happens if you set the value first with ‘sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576’?

Comment: @HenrikSöderlund It sounds like you are not on a real virtual machine, but on an OpenVZ container. In this case you might not be able to change the sysctl. You can confirm the virtualization type by running the command `hostnamectl` and viewing the output. If you do have OpenVZ you probably will need to go shopping for another VPS (and avoid OpenVZ).

Comment: @tolien this is printed on screen then: sysctl: setting key "fs.inotify.max_user_watches": Read-only file system

Comment: @MichaelHampton the command did not work, however, on the specs i can see "LXC Virtualization" - does this help?

Comment: @MichaelHampton virt-what gives: lxc

Comment: @HenrikSöderlund Yes, that's another container. You won't be able to solve this problem here. Find another VPS.

Comment: thanks @MichaelHampton, good to finally get to the root of the problem, bummer with how it needs to be solved! ;-) I will mark your helpful answer/comments as the solution in this case, many thanks!

Comment: I am on a real VM and the suggested solutions don't change anything for me either, but also without error message...

Answer (score 2):

To change ulimit settings for services you need to modify the systemd unit.

```
sudo systemctl edit --full nginx.service
```

And add the desired value to the service section

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=<integer>
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i did follow your suggestion and edited the file following your command, I set: LimitNOFILE=65536 - problem still persists I am afraid. Meanwhile I am following Michael's reply above which is not yet fully there

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file at /etc/security/limits.d/NN-custom.conf (replace NN with some number such as 20,30 ..etc). Name of the file does not matter but it should have extension .conf

Put the following contents in the above file (these are same as you mentioned in your post ,adjust as per your needs):

```
 nginx       soft    nofile      1024 
 nginx       hard    nofile      65536 
 root        hard    nofile      65536 
 root        soft    nofile      1024
```

run# sysctl -p /etc/security/limits.d/NN-custom.conf

Log off and log back in and restart your service.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue was with Debian 9 as well as Debian 10 buster.

The error was shown:

```
Failed to allocate directory watch: Too many open files
```

and increasing number of open files in Linux, didn't help, it was already maxed out:

```
fs.file-max = 9223372036854775807
```

The fix is to increase user instances count from 128 till something like this or more:

```
sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1024
```

and making it permanent as well with watches:

```
sudo bash -c 'cat <<EOF> /etc/sysctl.d/fs_inotify.conf
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 1024
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 1048576
EOF'
```